# How to adjust iFrame

Tags: html, iframe

I am not a html coder, I typically maintain content or modify html templates.  I have a catalog which is used by our internal sales staff.  It seems due to changes in today's monitor resolution the iframe is not adjusting itself or maybe the change in IE. Here is a link to the page below, I would appreciate anyone who could help correct this.

http://www.americantransmission.com/catalog.htm

Comment: also your `home` link on the left-hand side goes to `http://www.americantransmission.com/index.php` which gets a 404 error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add

```
style="height: 100%;"
```

to the div containing the Iframe.

```
<div align="center" style="height: 100%;">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="cat105b/login.php" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: so simple...and this is why I am NOT a coder...THX Secret Squirrel!

Comment: @user3099756 like anything, so simple to someone who is familiar with it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should see something like this :

```
<iframe width="700px" height="300px" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none" src="http://www.website.com">
</iframe>
```

This is just an example iframe but what you want to change is the `width` and `height` amounts to get your desired result.